# Finding the continuity of function

Tags: calculus

A function f is defined by:
$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
x^4 + 1, \  \text{ if }x < 0,\\ \\
        0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \text{ if } x = 0,\\ \\ 
        x^2 + 1,  \  \text{ if } x > 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Find the limit as $x \to 0$

I know that the one-sided limits as $x\to 0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$ are both $1.$
However, the $f(x) = 0$ part confuses me a bit. My guess is that the limit
does not exist, my reasoning being that because

$\lim_{x\to a} c = c$ , then

$\lim_{x \to 0} 0 = 0$

If this is not correct, then what bit of fundamental understanding am I
missing?

Answer (score 1):

The limit as x approaches zero exists and is $1$ as you say.  The limit does not care about what the function value is exactly at zero.  The fact that $f(0)=0 \neq \lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ says the function is not continuous there.